# How can i return null for a json property instead of "data": []

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, linq

I have decorated my property as

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public IEnumerable<Season> seasons { get; set; }
```

The problem arises with the following code which returns `"seasons": []` if no records exist.

```
from ul in userLeagues
select new Map.League
{
    id = ul.LeagueID,
    seasons = from ss in ul.Standings
              where inc.Seasons && ss.LeagueID == ul.LeagueID
              select new Map.Season
              {
                   seasonId = ss.Season.SeasonId,
                   seasonName = ss.Season.SeasonName
              })
}
```

Comment: I am curios.. why LINQ code will have problem.. It will return either list with data or empty list and JSON serializer will serialize it... This shouldn't be a problem as long the applicaiton which is parsing the JSON object complains about it.

Comment: This happens because the linq query will never return a null.  this will return an IQueryable, but when it evaluates the query it will return an empty list, not null.

Comment: LINQ won't return null, so your null handling attribute does nothing.

Comment: You do Queryable.ToList() and check the count and set the target variable to null if count is zero

Comment: Consider changing/simplifying your question's query, so that people who are trying to answer can run it in https://dotnetfiddle.net/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of hair pulling, success.

```
private IEnumerable<Season> _seasons;

[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public IEnumerable<Season> seasons
{
    get { return _seasons == null || _seasons.Count() == 0 ? null : _seasons; }
    set { _seasons = value; }
}
```

Special thanks to @ShaunLuttin for inspiring

Comment: this is a very clean solution, great idea! Instead of `_seasons == null` you could use `_seasons?.Count() == 0`. Also you should use `_seasons.Any()` instead of enumerating through seasons by using `Count()`

Comment: @Mafii changed to 
get { return _seasons  != null && _seasons .Any() ? _seasons  : null; }
since .Any() may throw an NullException?

Comment: You can use `_seasons?.Any()`. .Any will then only be executed if seasons is not null. Rest seems good, please don't forget to update your answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

### Here is a general answer

The `NullValueHandling` property handles null. LINQ's `select` never returns null and instead returns an empty `IEnumerable`. That is why you are seeing `“data”: []` in the resultant JSON.

To make the `NullValueHandling` property work, return null when the result will be an empty `IEnumerable`. For instance, you can adapt the following code to your situation.

[Run in DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IP5Y4O).

```
var foo = new List<string>();

var bar = !foo.Any()
    ? null
    : from f in foo select f;

Console.WriteLine(bar == null); // true
```

### This is how it might look for you

```
from ul in userLeagues
let standings = from ss in ul.Standings
                where inc.Seasons && ss.LeagueID == ul.LeagueID
select new Map.League
{
    id = ul.LeagueID,
    seasons = !standings.Any()
        ? null
        : from ss in standings
          select new Map.Season
          {
              seasonId = ss.Season.SeasonId,
              seasonName = ss.Season.SeasonName
          })
}
```

### Aside

Consider decomposing your queries into smaller chunks.